# Read file into mattrix(2D array)

Tags: c++

My input file is:

```
3 4
1 −3 8 2
3 10 1 0
2 −2 3 1
```

First line says the size of mattrix[3][4] in this case and I need to input the file into matrix. I found here many topics with similar problems but nothing worked for me. it seems like `vstup >> a >> b;` is not reading properly. Their values are always: `-858993460`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
int a,b;
double matica[100][100];
ifstream vstup("vstup.txt");

if (!vstup) {
    cout << "subot sa neda otvorit.\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

vstup >> a >> b;
for (int y = 0; y < a; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < b; x++) {
        vstup >>  matica[x][y];
    }
}
vstup.close();

cout << a << b;
    for (int y = 0; y < a; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < b; x++) {
        cout << matica[x][y] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}



system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Interesting, since it seems to work just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da40fd6580a1198d).

Comment: ok, i figured it out ... the problem was that i coppied the matrix from pdf file and pasted it into text doc. and it couldnt read "pdf characters"? i just lost few chromosomes on finding this bug...

Comment: If you are interested why it did not work, I suggest that you open your file with a hex editor and take a closer look.